# The compare function for bcrypt doesn't work for me

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, bcrypt

```
// this was my post request
app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  try {
    const studentSameEmail = await Student.find({ email });
    if (studentSameEmail.length !== 0) {
      return res
        .status(409)
        .json({ message: "A user with this email already exists." });
    }

    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
    console.log(hashedPassword);

    const student = await Student.create({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      password: hashedPassword,
    });
    await student.save();
    res.status(200).json(student);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message: error.message });
  }
});

// this was my get request
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  const students = await Student.find({});

  res.status(200).json(students);
});

app.get("/:email/:password", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password } = req.params;

  const studentWithEmail = await Student.findOne({ email });

  if (!studentWithEmail) {
    return res.status(409).json({
      message: `No student with email ${email} found.`,
    });
  }

  if (await bcrypt.compare(password, studentWithEmail.password)) {
    return res.status(200).json(studentWithEmail);
  } else {
    return res
      .status(409)
      .json({
        message: `Student with email ${email} but no password ${password}`,
      });
  }
});
```

I encrypted the password from the requests body in the post request but when I tried to use the bcrypt.compare() function in the get request to compare the hashed password with the unhashed version to implement a login system but it didn't work.

Comment: Have you confirmed that password and studentWithEmail are received correctly? Your usage seems correct

Comment: What didn't work? Which JSON response did you get back? Was there an error thrown?